# rsync: how to exclude directories with special character via external exclude file

Tags: bash, command-line, rsync

I'm trying to back up a server with an rsync script automated with cron.  Right now I'm using the command:

rsync -avz --progress --exclude-from "/Users/user/Scripts/exclude.txt" -e ssh user@server:$REMOTE_PATH $LOCAL_PATH > /tmp/rsync.log

with $REMOTE_PATH and $LOCAL_PATH defined in the bash script.

I have a directory called #recycle that I'm trying to skip, and am unsure how to exclude it with a file.  If I use the option --exclude '#recycle/', then it skips the directory just fine.  However, if I include the option above with an --exclude-from tag, with the file only containing the line:

```
#recycle/
```

then it doesn't work.  I've also tried `\#recycle/`, but escaping the pound sign doesn't seem to fix the issue.  I'm pretty sure that the pound is causing all of the issues, but I don't have any control over the directory names.  Any thoughts on how to fix this?

thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lines starting with `#` are ignored in exclude files, yes.

You can instead use `[#]recycle` which matches the same thing, but is not discarded as a comment.

Comment: Thanks! That was it!  I tried using a '\' as an escape character, but this worked just great!

Comment: This worked great.  My Synology drives adds the '#recycle' to folders where one has enabled that feature on a shared folder.  Leaving his commend in case anyone else has an issue with rsync on Synology.

Comment: Fellow Synology user here also using Rsync. Was having the same issue. Thanks!